# what's additional asset processing stand for in webpack work procedure?

Tags: javascript, webpack

> 91% additional asset
>   processing435432ms additional asset
>   processing

When transpilling, there will be some log in the console, I am wondering what's `additional asset processing` stand for?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/ProgressPlugin.js#L114) for the progress plugin, this is related to the [`additional-assets`](https://webpack.js.org/api/compilation/#additional-assets-async) compiler hook.

## From the docs

> *Create additional assets for the compilation*
>
> Here's an example that downloads an image.
>
> ```
> compiler.plugin('compilation', function(compilation) {
>   compilation.plugin('additional-assets', function(callback) {
>     download('https://img.shields.io/npm/v/webpack.svg', function(resp) {
>       if(resp.status === 200) {
>         compilation.assets['webpack-version.svg'] = toAsset(resp);
>         callback();
>       } else {
>         callback(new Error('[webpack-example-plugin] Unable to download the image'));
>       }
>     })
>   });
> });
> ```

From this, we can assume that plugins will use this hook to add additional assets to a given compilation.